# Save graph with graphstream

Tags: java, graphviz, graphstream

In my java project I'm using graphs with this library "[graphstream](http://graphstream-project.org/)".

I need to save my graph in a type file "Graphviz Dot", i.e.: nodes, edges, node attributes, edge attributes.
I usually do in this way to save my graph in the file:

```
Graph graph = new MultiGraph(strId, strictChecking, autoCreate);
// create nodes, edges, node attributes, edge attributes...
FileSinkDOT fs = new FileSinkDOT();
fs.writeAll(graph, filePath);
```

Problem: When I open or load the  file, I can't see edge attributes.
Anyone knows "graphstream" and knows can I save this file?

Thank you for all your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by now. Check the [nightly builds](http://graphstream-project.org/pub/1.x/nightly-build/last/).